# React Select displaying irrelevant/unnecessary details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I am using react-select v2.4.4 for a dropdown list in a react v15.6.2 project with material-ui. However, the react-select component is displaying some unnecessary details whose source I am unable to find. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVEhF.png) shows the components used in my code. Row 3 with title IAE is the react-select component. When I click on the dropdown arrow, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LgtZ.png) is what is being displayed. This description is nowhere present in the code. Can someone guide me as to what could be causing this issue. Is it a known issue or a one-off case that I am facing and how can I resolve it.

Edit: I have pasted the react-select part of the code I am using.

PS. I cannot upgrade the react-select version since this is the latest my project is able to support.

```
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
]

<tr>
  <td>IAE</td>
  <td style={{ width: 100 }}>
    <Select
      options={options}
      placeholder={'Enter Value'}
      isSearchable={true}
    />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: I have added the react-select part of the code I am using.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io)...

Comment: this is most likely a css problem, try to check your styles